# Should I hide anything on a public GitHub repo - Flutter + Firebase project

Tags: firebase, flutter, github, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am doing my first commit of a Flutter app to a public repository on my GitHub account. It utilizes Firebase Auth and Firestore. Are there any sensitive files / keys that I should worry about hiding/securing? Such as the google-services.json file? If so, do I just need to use the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Yes, [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is the right tool for excluding files from being tracked.

Comment: I appreciate that. Having kept everything private to this point, I am nervous about exposing anything sensitive.